# Spring Roo Timestamp issue: 1.2.2 as Date, 1.2.4 as Calendar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, aop, spring-roo

I have a Spring Roo (1.2.2) project that I'm trying to build.  From a clean SCM checkout, a `mvn clean install` builds nicely.

However, when I import the project into my SpringSource Tool Suite IDE (packaged with m2eclipse and Roo 1.2.4), then Eclipse invokes `roo` to update the POM's `<roo.version>`, which then updates the entity aspects.  After this, all of the methods with `java.util.Date` paremeters/return types no longer work, as compilation produces `symbol not found` errors on the `Date` fields.

How do I get Roo to generate aspects with a type of `Date` instead of `Calendar`?

### Error Log

```
[ERROR] /Users/jjzabkar/project/src/main/java/com/so/FooBar.java:209:0::0 The method setTokenExpires(Calendar) in the type FooBar is not applicable for the arguments (Date)  
[ERROR] error at account.setLastaccessTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

### Research

- Checked & followed all recommendations in the project's [Upgrade to any new Release appendix](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/upgrade.html#upgrade-any).
- Haven't been able to find or build ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo)) Roo version 1.2.2--no `bin\roo`; building from source fails.
- Investigated Roo add-ons that add various timestamp fields, but didn't see any mention of them in the project `log.roo` file: [spring-roo-addon-audit-timestamp](https://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-audit-timestamp/wiki/GettingStarted), [spring-roo-addon-timestamp](https://github.com/rcaloras/spring-roo-addon-timestamp), nor were their annotations present on the originally checked out files.

### Old POM

```
<roo.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</roo.version>
```

### Updated POM

```
<roo.version>1.2.4.RELEASE</roo.version>
```

### `FooBar.java` Entity

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(versionField = "", table = "foo_bar")
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
public class FooBar {
}
```

### Aspect **BEFORE** for Roo Version 1.2.2

```
privileged aspect FooBar_Roo_DbManaged {
    ...
    @Column(name = "lastaccess_time")
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "M-")
    private Date FooBar.lastaccessTime;

    public Date FooBar.getLastaccessTime() {
        return lastaccessTime;
    }

    public void FooBar.setLastaccessTime(Date lastaccessTime) {
        this.lastaccessTime = lastaccessTime;
    }

}
```

### Aspect **AFTER** for Roo Version 1.2.4

```
privileged aspect FooBar_Roo_DbManaged {
    ...
    @Column(name = "lastaccess_time")
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "MM")
    private Calendar FooBar.lastaccessTime;

    public Calendar FooBar.getLastaccessTime() {
        return lastaccessTime;
    }

    public void FooBar.setLastaccessTime(Calendar lastaccessTime) {
        this.lastaccessTime = lastaccessTime;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before update to Roo 1.2.4 you should push-in Date fields to .java, by doing that Roo won't generate them again and won't change the type to Calendar.